# F(x=y/a)な関数を基に、F1(y=a1x),F2(y=a2x) ~みたいに変換したい

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, wsl

原型のF(x=s/a)から、a1,a2,a3 ~ の定数項で変化を持たせた F1(y) F2(y) F3(y) ~ を作りたい。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

原型のF(x)が下のコード

```
from scipy.special import kv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np
import math
from math import gamma

xs = np.logspace(-4, 2, 10000)

f = lambda z: kv(5/3,z)
F = [quad(f,x,np.inf)[0]*x for x in xs]

a = gamma(1/3) 
G = [(4*math.pi/np.sqrt(3)/a)*(x/2)**(1/3) for x in xs]
H = [((math.pi/2)**(1/2))*(x**(1/2))*(math.exp(-x))for x in xs]



def A(x,F,G,H):
   if x <= 5.0*1e-3:
       g =G
   elif 5.0*1e-3 < x < 30:
       g =F
   elif 30 <= x:
       g =H
   return g

vec_A = np.vectorize(A)
y = vec_A(xs,F,G,H)
```

ここから、x→ s/a1,s/a2 ~ みたいに変化させたいけど書き方の見当がつかない

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/282614